# Does hibernate generate table and alter database with model to mySQL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i am new to spring mvc and hibernate.
in aspnet MVC when we make model and set attribute its migrate to SQL and create table with our class and alter tables.
is there anything like this in hibernate and spring MVC?

Comment: Hibernate does this by default. Did you try?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do

Comment: @BackSlash in lynda videos i've seen he first make table with sql in script to my sql and then make model... thats why i am asking this in aspnet mvc after adding migration it will alter database after changes

Comment: you can use spring-boot that does the same thing. you need to define Entity class with column attribute and it will create table.

Comment: @Shahid after create entity class and models . after run it will automaticaly create tables and handle relations?

Comment: @Shahid im using spring mvc

Comment: Yes, it handles everything. https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Not sure about spring-mvc but spring-boot gives you this feature.

Comment: thank you for assistance